# Is there a way to include a trend-line using my left Y-axis in a 'Line and Clustered column chart' in Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi

Is there a way to include a trend-line using my left Y-axis in a 'Line and Clustered column chart' in Power BI?

I achieved it in Excel
[image]

With this (sample) data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hk5jqpsol7m248w/sample%20Excel%20combo%20chart.txt?dl=0

Comment: Does [this](https://geekdecoders.blogspot.com/2019/02/how-to-add-trend-line-in-power-bi-chart.html) help?

Comment: Hi Jon,
No unfortunately it does not.
That seems to be an older post, without the current Power BI version.
Also, it focusses on column-chart. not a combination of the column and line chart.

Comment: Provide a sample data set in text format (**NOT** as a screenshot which cannot be copy/pasted into Excel) and I'll try to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added a link to a text file.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add a single trendline as you show.  You can add a trendline to a Line and Clustered Column chart, provided the x-axis is Dates, but trendlines are added to all of the data series.  See this  [discussion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane) for more information.

Comment: Hi Ron,
Thanks for your reply!
You are right, I thought so already, I had very little hope to begin with.
Kind regards,